# Why I can't create files using NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Debugging indicates no erros.
But I just cant find the text file anywhere.
I'm so confused.

```
NSString *outPath = @"kousuanjuan.txt";
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:outPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
outFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:outPath];
if (outFile == Nil) {
    NSLog(@"Failed.");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Is this for iOS or OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the path you are trying to save to is just `kousuanjuan.txt` then you most likely don't have permission to create a file there. Not clear how debugging indicates no errors as your code shows no error parameters or validations:

1. `createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:` returns a `BOOL` - check it
2. `fileExistsAtPath:` - use it
3. `isWritableFileAtPath:` - verify it

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved. I find that the file is created at the directory where the executable lays.